# Issue adding Lottie animation sublayer capture session

Tags: swift, lottie

Essentially I currently do the following below to display a square on top of the captureSession, but I would like to replace the square with a Lottie animation - having trouble understanding how I can place and play the animation instead of displaying the static square:

```swift
captureSession.startRunning()

let scannerOverlayPreviewLayer = ScannerOverlayPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
scannerOverlayPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
scannerOverlayPreviewLayer.maskSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
scannerOverlayPreviewLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
scannerOverlayPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
self.view.layer.addSublayer(scannerOverlayPreviewLayer)
```

**Animation:**

```swift
private var animationView: AnimationView?
animationView = .init(name: "scan")
animationView!.frame = view.bounds
animationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
animationView!.loopMode = .loop
animationView!.animationSpeed = 0.5
view.addSubview(animationView!)
animationView!.play()
```

I intention is to place the animation in the center of the screen. The size of the animation is width: 200, height: 200 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to place Lottie in the middle of the screen?
I recommend you to make a view in the middle first and then set up Lottie in it.

First, create a view with a height of 200 and a width of 200 in the middle of the screen.

```swift
        let myView = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

Then insert the AnimationView into the view you created. You can set up the same thing with Lottie.

```swift
       let animationView = AnimationView(name: "scan")
        
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myView.bounds.width, height: myView.bounds.height)
```

Comment: It is not presenting in the center of the screen - see my example of what does work above self.view.layer.addSublayer..for some reason that does work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MarkLyson Have you tried writing this code? myView.addSubview(animationView)